# How to use com objects in msvbvm60.dll or vba6.dll, e.g. use module datetime

Tags: visual-c++, com

There are many com objects in msvbvm60.dll or vba6.dll, and there are two type libraries in there.
My question is how to use them(in VC++) without any docs, e.g. use module "DateTime" function "Now".
You can view VBA "Visual Basic For Applications" by using "oleview.exe" in windows sdk bin folder.

This is a part of the VBA idl generated by oleview:

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: msvbvm60.dll

[
  uuid(000204EF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046),
  version(6.0),
  helpstring("Visual Basic For Applications"),
  helpfile("VBA.HLP"),
  helpcontext(0x000f6791)
]
library VBA
{
    // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    // Forward declare all types defined in this typelib
    interface _HiddenInterface;
    interface _ErrObject;
    interface _Collection;

***// omit some definitions here***

    [
      dllname("VBA6.DLL"),
      uuid(37D75300-2BCC-1069-82D8-00DD010EDFAA),
      helpcontext(0x000f6ebf)
    ]
    module DateTime {
        [entry(610), propget, helpcontext(0x000f6d5e)]
        VARIANT _stdcall _B_var_Date();
        [entry(549), propput, helpcontext(0x000f6d5e)]
        void _stdcall _B_str_Date([in] BSTR rhs);
        [entry(548), propput, helpcontext(0x000f6d5e)]
        void _stdcall _B_var_Date([in] VARIANT* rhs);
        [entry(609), propget, helpcontext(0x000f6d5e)]
        BSTR _stdcall _B_str_Date();
        [entry(538), helpcontext(0x000f64f8)]
        VARIANT _stdcall DateSerial(
                        [in] short Year, 
                        [in] short Month, 
                        [in] short Day);
        [entry(540), helpcontext(0x000f64f9)]
        VARIANT _stdcall DateValue([in] BSTR Date);
        [entry(542), helpcontext(0x000f64fa)]
        VARIANT _stdcall Day([in] VARIANT* Date);
        [entry(543), helpcontext(0x000f652b)]
        VARIANT _stdcall Hour([in] VARIANT* Time);
        [entry(544), helpcontext(0x000f654e)]
        VARIANT _stdcall Minute([in] VARIANT* Time);
        [entry(545), helpcontext(0x000f6551)]
        VARIANT _stdcall Month([in] VARIANT* Date);
        [entry(546), propget, helpcontext(0x000f6556)]
        VARIANT _stdcall Now();
        [entry(547), helpcontext(0x000f6573)]
        VARIANT _stdcall Second([in] VARIANT* Time);
        [entry(612), propget, helpcontext(0x000f6d5f)]
        VARIANT _stdcall _B_var_Time();
        [entry(551), propput, helpcontext(0x000f6d5f)]
        void _stdcall _B_str_Time([in] BSTR rhs);
        [entry(550), propput, helpcontext(0x000f6d5f)]
        void _stdcall _B_var_Time([in] VARIANT* rhs);
        [entry(611), propget, helpcontext(0x000f6d5f)]
        BSTR _stdcall _B_str_Time();
        [entry(535), propget, helpcontext(0x000f6593)]
        single _stdcall Timer();
        [entry(539), helpcontext(0x000f6594)]
        VARIANT _stdcall TimeSerial(
                        [in] short Hour, 
                        [in] short Minute, 
                        [in] short Second);
        [entry(541), helpcontext(0x000f6595)]
        VARIANT _stdcall TimeValue([in] BSTR Time);
        [entry(552), helpcontext(0x000f65a2)]
        VARIANT _stdcall Weekday(
                        [in] VARIANT* Date, 
                        [in, optional, defaultvalue(1)] VbDayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeek);
        [entry(553), helpcontext(0x000f65a7)]
        VARIANT _stdcall Year([in] VARIANT* Date);
        [entry(661), helpcontext(0x000f7566)]
        VARIANT _stdcall DateAdd(
                        [in] BSTR Interval, 
                        [in] double Number, 
                        [in] VARIANT* Date);
        [entry(662), helpcontext(0x000f74d6)]
        VARIANT _stdcall DateDiff(
                        [in] BSTR Interval, 
                        [in] VARIANT* Date1, 
                        [in] VARIANT* Date2, 
                        [in, optional, defaultvalue(1)] VbDayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeek, 
                        [in, optional, defaultvalue(1)] VbFirstWeekOfYear FirstWeekOfYear);
        [entry(663), helpcontext(0x000f74d7)]
        VARIANT _stdcall DatePart(
                        [in] BSTR Interval, 
                        [in] VARIANT* Date, 
                        [in, optional, defaultvalue(1)] VbDayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeek, 
                        [in, optional, defaultvalue(1)] VbFirstWeekOfYear FirstWeekOfYear);
        [entry(700), propget, helpcontext(0x00110c12)]
        VbCalendar _stdcall Calendar();
        [entry(699), propput, helpcontext(0x00110c12)]
        void _stdcall Calendar([in] VbCalendar rhs);
    };

***// omit some definitions here***

    [
      uuid(A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB),
      helpcontext(0x000f8c67)
    ]
    coclass Collection {
        [default] interface _Collection;
    };
};
```

How to use them(in VC++) without any docs, e.g. use module "DateTime" function "Now".

Comment: You shouldn't need that. Most of these are available (not exactly with the same syntax, sometimes a bit indirectly) from oleaut32.dll https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/ for example you can build Now using SystemTimeToVariantTime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-systemtimetovarianttime PS: OleAut ("Ole Automation") was invented for VB...

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you for your reply. Yes, you are correct, but I just want to know how to handle this kind of situations.

Comment: IDL's module can mean lots of things https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/attributes/module-cpp, but in this case, it's of dll-type, so they are exported functions with ordinal ("entry"). So, 546 for the "Now" entry correspond to the "rtcGetPresentDate" (ordinal 546) function in msvbvm60.dll

Comment: @SimonMourier You're great! This information inspires me. Thank you very much